# plotting the listed value in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, matplotlib

Hii experts i have written a simple python script for accessing the list of values and does some calculation in for loop,while plotting(x,y) it doesn't give the plot.My programme is given below.i hope some expert will help me rectifying the problem.Thanks in advance.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: you cant plot a point

Answer (score 1):

```
a=1978780
b=[4,40,90,100,600,785,900]


for i in range(len(b)):
    zx=math.exp(b[i]/a)*5
#     print(b[i],zx)
    plt.scatter(b[i],zx)
plt.show()
```

This will solve the issue. (But not recommended try the other solution, fast and efficient)

Or this

```
a=1978780
b=np.array([4,40,90,100,600,785,900])


zx=np.exp(b/a)*5
plt.plot(b,zx)
plt.show()
```

[image]

or this

```
a=1978780
b=np.array([4,40,90,100,600,785,900])


for i in range(len(b)):
    zx=math.exp(b[i]/a)*5
#     print(b[i],zx)
    plt.scatter(b[i],zx)
plt.ylim(4.999,5.005)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the first solution, iterating is no use in numpy arrays

Comment: @WasifHasan i know, i just wanted to keep the structure as his suggested code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you apply the vectorized operation on the numpy array and plot it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


a=1978780
b=np.array([4,40,90,100,600,785,900])

zx=np.exp(b/a)*5

plt.plot(b,zx)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use numpy's ability to work on arrays. That way, no need to iterate over lists anymore and you can write your function in a single line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = 1978780
b = np.array([4, 40, 90, 100, 600, 785, 900])
zx = np.exp(b/a)*5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(b, zx)
fig.show()
```